# Anyone can explain this code to me?

Tags: vb.net

```
Try
    Me.Validate()
    Me.ItemBindingSource.EndEdit()
    Me.TableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(Me.InventoryDataSet)
Catch ex As Exception 
    MessageBox.Show("Duplicate Record", "Data Input Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK,MessageBoxIcon.Information)
 End Try
```

I don understand how it works, what is `me.validate()`?

Answer (score 0):

> The process of checking whether entered data is what it needs to be for the system to work correctly.

From http://visualbasic.about.com/od/quicktips/qt/ValidationGuide2.htm

Or I guess you mean :

> To check whether an input value is in its correct format or not.